# Add text from one layer to polygons in second layer

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I have two layers. In first there are points with attributes in the form of text. In the second layer there are polygons. I need to connect the polygons with numbers that are above these polygons into one layer. How do this?
[image]

screen what I am doing
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to create a virtual layer:

Replace `Grid` and `pointlayer345` with your layer names in the code below.

This will result in a layer of all polygons with their attributes, and `numer` attribute from the points intersecting:

```sql
select polygon.*, point.numer
from Grid polygon
left join pointlayer345 point
on st_intersects(polygon.geometry, point.geometry)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

On the polygon layer, use this expression (e.g. in Field calculator to create a new attribute or as source of a dynamic label):

```
overlay_contains ('point_layer_name', "attribute_name")
```

Output of the function [`overlay_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) is an array of the values contained in the attribute field `"attribute_name"` (2nd argument) of the layer `point_layer_name` (1st argument).

If you want to get just the first element, add `[0]` at the end of the expression. If you want to convert the result into a string, enclose the whole expression from above as argument into an [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-to-string) function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you specify where exactly to use this function. I ran it in calculator. Unfortunately it didn't add the numbers to the polygons for me.

Comment: Weird. I do not understand this. In the preview calculator, it shows what number it will assign. After running the function, the added column in the polygon layer is empty.

Comment: Use field calculator. You must select the correct field type: text(string) and make sure you convert the array to a text. If it doesn't work, add a screenshot of what you try to your initial question

Comment: If you need to property to belong to your Polygon layer, as mentioned above the "field calculator" will do so : open the Polygon layer "attribute table", add the new (text) field there with the "field calculator". You can then re-use this new property of your Polygon layer for whatever need : will be there if you export it, is available to Label your polygons, ...

Comment: Or create a virtual field in the same way as descibed by @Kasper - this has the advantage that it is dynamic: thus it changes if you move / add / delete points or polygons

Comment: Still the same result = null but in the preview result is good. After click ok there is null in column layer polygons.

Comment: @WojciechK this does not help us to find where the problem is. If you want an answer, please provide more information about what you are doing. Please post a screenshot (in your initial question), showing where and how you use the expression. Sharing your data+project could also help. And: are you sure you changed the names `point_layer_name` and `attribute_name` correctly?

Comment: See the last paragraph of my answer, you ignored this. You get the correct output (see preview in the expression string builder), but as an array, not a text. Adding e.g. `[0]` at the end of the expression or enclose the whole expression into a `array_to_string()` function should solve your problem.

Comment: Super it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this site tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235